# How to solve these equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm considering a coursera astronomy course and two of the prerequisites are listed below :

[image]

Could provide me with an explanation of how to solve points 2 & 3 above ?

Comment: 1) logarithms 2) Basic equations

Comment: @Gautam, do you think that's helpful?

Comment: user, you're not going to get "a familiarity with the rudiments of high-school algebra" from an answer on math.stackexchange. You're going to need to find a refresher or bridging course somewhere, and do that before you try the astronomy course.

Comment: @Gerry Sorry. But I fail to get what is he looking for. By logarithms, I mean either using the Clarks table or the calculator or learning to manage coefficients and mantissa separately. By Basic equations, I mean transposition rules.

Comment: There's no need for logarithms in question 1. $-2.3 \times 10^{13} \times .8 \times 10^{-28} = (-2.3 \times .8) \times (10^{13} \times 10^{-28}) = -1.84 \times 10^{-15}$.

Comment: @user470184, Gerry's advice is a sound one, imo: if you're serious about a course in astronomy you're going to need waaaaay more than answers to two questions. Think of taking a remedial course in algebra/geometry/calculus in that college/university

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you compute a product of the form $(a\cdot 10^n)(b\cdot 10^m)$ all you have to do is to compute $ab$ first, and then $10^n\cdot 10^m$ using the property: $10^m\cdot 10^n=10^{m+n}$. If $ab$ is greater than $10$ or less than $1$ then it is recommended to write it as a number $p$ such that $1\leqslant |p|\lt10$ times a power of $10$ and then repeat the same procedure we did. In this particular example: $$
   \begin{align}(-2.3\times10^{13})\cdot(0.8\times 10^{-28})&=[(-2.3)\times(0.8)]\times[10^{13}\times 10^{-28}]\\
   &=(-1.84)\times(10^{13-28})\\ &=-1.84\times 10^{-15}.
   \end{align}$$
2. To prove that $$\rm\frac{2GMr}{D^3}=\frac{Gm}{r^2}\iff D=\left(\frac{2M}m\right)^{1/3}r$$ you really have to be very fluent at algebra. For that particular case, you have to multiply both sides by $\rm D^3$ then regroup all the extra terms in the RHS and then take the cubic root to *eliminate* that exponential power. If you don't know how to do this then you surely have to revise your algebra before taking any astronomy courses.

As *Gerry* said: You're going to need to find a refresher or bridging course somewhere, and do that **before** you try the astronomy course. Or in the case of self-study, go look for some good intros to algebra, precalculus, and calc.

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: im taking a course in linear algebra. will this provide a good grounding ?

Comment: @user470184 Could you provide me with what will be discussed in that course?

Comment: I'm not sure but here are course details : MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c

Comment: @user470184 In addition to that go through [Khan|Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math)'s section on algebra, and precalc **first**.